# How to use write_single_register function in pymodbustcp library

Tags: modbus-tcp, pymodbus, pymodbus3, pymodbustcp

Using RTDS's MODBUS communication protocol, we intend to communicate with Python using the [pyModbusTCP](https://github.com/sourceperl/pyModbusTCP) library. The register was assigned by mapping the components of the system modelled by RTDS as follows

```
# RIR: Read Input Registers (16 bit word, read only- outputs from RTDS) 
RIR:    1   P4_real
RIR:    2   Q4_real
RIR:    3   P5_real
RIR:    4   Q5_real

RIR:    5   Bus1Arms_real
RIR:    6   Bus1Brms_real
RIR:    7   Bus1Crms_real

RIR:    8   Bus2Arms_real
RIR:    9   Bus2Brms_real
RIR:    10  Bus2Crms_real

RIR:    11  Bus3Arms_real
RIR:    12  Bus3Brms_real
RIR:    13  Bus3Crms_real

RIR:    14  Bus4Arms_real
RIR:    15  Bus4Brms_real
RIR:    16  Bus4Crms_real

RIR:    17  Bus5Arms_real
RIR:    18  Bus5Brms_real
RIR:    19  Bus5Crms_real

RIR:    20  Bus1_RMS_real
RIR:    21  Bus2_RMS_real
RIR:    22  Bus3_RMS_real
RIR:    23  Bus4_RMS_real
RIR:    24  Bus5_RMS_real

RIR:    25  Station_frequency

RIR:    26  EV1_pcharge
RIR:    27  EV2_pcharge
RIR:    28  EV3_pcharge
RIR:    29  EV4_pcharge
RIR:    30  EV5_pcharge
RIR:    31  EV6_pcharge
RIR:    32  EV7_pcharge
RIR:    33  EV8_pcharge

RIR:    34  EV1_Pref
RIR:    35  EV2_Pref
RIR:    36  EV3_Pref
RIR:    37  EV4_Pref
RIR:    38  EV5_Pref
RIR:    39  EV6_Pref
RIR:    40  EV7_Pref
RIR:    41  EV8_Pref

RIR:    42  DBLK1
RIR:    43  DBLK2

# ROR: Read Output Registers (16 bit word, read/write - inputs to RTDS)

ROR:    1   EV1_Pref
ROR:    2   EV2_Pref
ROR:    3   EV3_Pref
ROR:    4   EV4_Pref
ROR:    5   EV5_Pref
ROR:    6   EV6_Pref
ROR:    7   EV7_Pref
ROR:    8   EV8_Pref
ROR:    9   DBLK1
ROR:    10  DBLK2

END
```

Reading the value of the component using `read_input_register()` was successful, but the value of the component did not change when using `write_single_register()`. How can we solve these problems?

```py
import time
from pyModbusTCP.client import ModbusClient
try:
c = ModbusClient(host='172.27.206.104', port=502)
except ValueError:
print("Error with host or port params")
 

iter = 1
while True:
    print(iter, "sec")
    P4_real = c.read_input_registers(1)
    Q4_real = c.read_input_registers(2)
    P5_real = c.read_input_registers(3)
    Q5_real = c.read_input_registers(4)
    Bus1Arms_real = c.read_input_registers(5)
    Bus1Brms_real = c.read_input_registers(6)
    Bus1Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(7)
    Bus2Arms_real = c.read_input_registers(8)
    Bus2Brms_real = c.read_input_registers(9)
    Bus2Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(10)
    Bus3Arms_real = c.read_input_registers(11)
    Bus3Brms_real = c.read_input_registers(12)
    Bus3Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(13)
    Bus4Arms_real = c.read_input_registers(14)
    Bus4Brms_real = c.read_input_registers(15)
    Bus4Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(16)
    Bus5Arms_real = c.read_input_registers(17)
    Bus5Brms_real = c.read_input_registers(18)
    Bus5Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(19)
    Bus5Crms_real = c.read_input_registers(19)
    Bus1_RMS_real = c.read_input_registers(20)
    Bus2_RMS_real = c.read_input_registers(21)
    Bus3_RMS_real = c.read_input_registers(22)
    Bus4_RMS_real = c.read_input_registers(23)
    Bus5_RMS_real = c.read_input_registers(24)
    Station_frequency = c.read_input_registers(25)
    EV1_p = c.read_input_registers(26)
    EV2_p = c.read_input_registers(27)
    EV3_p = c.read_input_registers(28)
    EV4_p = c.read_input_registers(29)
    EV5_p = c.read_input_registers(30)
    EV6_p = c.read_input_registers(31)
    EV7_p = c.read_input_registers(32)
    EV8_p = c.read_input_registers(33)
    charge1 = c.read_input_registers(34)
    charge2 = c.read_input_registers(35)
    charge3 = c.read_input_registers(36)
    charge4 = c.read_input_registers(37)
    charge5 = c.read_input_registers(38)
    charge6 = c.read_input_registers(39)
    charge7 = c.read_input_registers(40)
    charge8 = c.read_input_registers(41)
    switch1 = c.read_input_registers(42)
    switch2 = c.read_input_registers(43
    if iter>=2:
        c.write_single_register(1,0)
        c.write_single_register(2,0)
        c.write_single_register(3,0)
        c.write_single_register(4,0)
        c.write_single_register(5,0)
        c.write_single_register(6,0)
        c.write_single_register(7,0)
        c.write_single_register(8,0)
```

It is expected that the value of the component will change in real time during the real-time simulation process of rtds using write_single_register.

Comment: In your example `iter` is not changed so `if iter>=2:` will always be false (please aim for a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Input registers are read only. `write_single_register` sends Modbus command `0x06` - "Write Single Holding Register"; it's unsurprising this does not impact input registers (with some devices it might but you need to be specific about the device you are communicating with).